# How can i reuse a created and deactivated virtual environment

Tags: virtual, environment, reusability

I have created virtual environments i would like to reuse.
How can i do it by using:
`pip install virtualenv`
Created virtualenv using: 
`virtualenv env_name`
Activated using:
`env_name\Scripts\activate.bat`

Installed packages
Deactivate it using
`deactivate`
I would like to reuse it.
Help

Answer (score 1):

Just activate it again

```
env_name\Scripts\activate.bat
```